# How to send a Twilio MMS via AWS Lambda using C#

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, twilio

First, I'm a total noob with AWS Lambda so I wanted to see if anyone can point me in the right direction to setting up an AWS Lambda function that will send a Twilio MMS message that would be triggered by an upload of an image to an S3 bucket? I guess C# isn't a hard set requirement but it would be nice since that is the language that I'm currently working with.

I'm currently doing this via my app but want to offload this to an AWS Lambda function if at all possible.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I'm neither a C# expert nor very familiar with AWS Lamda, but [this post](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-csharp.html) here should get you started.

And [this documentation page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/csharp-dotnet-framework) explains how to send messages with C#. So the only thing you need to do is add the Twilio Account SID and Auth key to the Lamda environment variables, and there you go.

```cs
// Install the C# / .NET helper library from twilio.com/docs/csharp/install

using System;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
        // and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
        string accountSid = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
        string authToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");

        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var message = MessageResource.Create(
            body: "Join Earth's mightiest heroes. Like Kevin Bacon.",
            from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+15017122661"),
            to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+15558675310")
        );

        Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
    }
}
```